# Windows 7 Explorer "Back button" right-click does not provide a "history menu"

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, context-menu

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Windows Explorer (not IE)
2. Navigate to folder A
3. Navigate to subfolder B
4. Navigate to subfolder C
5. Right-click on the Back button in the upper left corner, and it should show a history menu with the items:  A, B

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium.

This used to happen on my old installation, but now I restored to the Acer's OEM build which I think does not have this feature.

Am I misremembering, or does the retail release of Windows 7 contain the feature while the OEM does not?

I had hoped this feature would come back by using Windows Update, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

The history menu that you are referring to is known as the **Recent Pages** drop-down menu. You do not **right-click** the back button (as you would in a web browser), instead you click the arrow to the right of the forward button.

[image: Recent Pages]